# To save into variable the certain 'find' result,

Tags: bash, variables, find

How do we save into variable the certain `find` result, in e.g,

`find ~+ \( -maxdepth 1 -type d  -exec find '{}' -size 9 print \) -o type f printf "%p\n" -o`  ...
                              `^`__

the pointer tells to the point in which only a variable should get the value / string which is only one since in one (the current) dir. only one unique name of any type is allowed, and ignore the other of many find results

Any useful help is gratified

Comment: var=$(find .....)

Answer (score 0):

You need first to decide, whether the variable is supposed to hold a scalar or an array. Since you are likely expecting more than one line as the output of the command and later will process these lines individually, instead of treating them as one amorph chunk, an array is probably the better choice:

```
find_output=( $(find ....) )
```

Of course this prohibits you to place the value into your environment. If this is a requirement, you have to bite the bullet and use a scalar:

```
export find_output=$(find ....)
```